# How to map / to index.html in AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm using API Gateway as a proxy to fan out requests to different services based  on the requested url. For example, /api/${proxy+} is mapped to an EKS cluster with my REST api behind it. But everything that's not under /api is mapped to an S3 bucket with my static files. That's the /${proxy+} part as seen below. It's all working, except that when I request / it returns "Missing Authentication Token." Weird, because /${proxy} doesn't require API tokens or authentication of any kind.

My setup is shown below:

[image]

[image]

I have tried a variation where I added a method on "/" and return index.html specifically from that S3 bucket

[image]

Comment: "Missing authentication error" is the message API Gateway returns for non-existing routes, so that can be a first hint at what could be going on there.

Comment: Did you deploy the second version after adding it? This method should work.

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: @Calicoder have you found a solution?

Comment: did any suggestions here work for you @Calicoder ?